# Solve the Modified Question problem

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059580/distributed-lock-service), and got an answer with 3 upvotes.
Then, I edited my question in such a way that the answer is no longer relevant.

The question will no longer appear as an unanswered question, and so will have little change of being promptly answered.

Assuming I really want my question answered, and I consider it unanswered, what should I do in this case? (I decided to [re-ask the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070495/distributed-lock-service-over-mysql-gigaspaces-netapp), with no great success so far).

Comment: If the new question is so different the old answer is no longer relevent, the question is probably quite different, so I would ask the new question separately straight away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should have asked a new question and referenced the original as explanation. From what you've said the new version of the question was sufficiently different to make it not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how many people actually use the "unanswered questions" tab - I know I don't.

Editing the question will bump it briefly, so it should get a bit more attention - and if you make it very clear (i.e. in a bold bit of text in the question) that you've edited the question, that should help to make it clear what's going on.

In some ways asking the modified question *without* editing the original (but linking to it for background) would have been better, so that the original question would still stand alone as a question with a valid answer.

Comment: I mainly use the unanswered questions.

Comment: People use the unanswered questions, because they seek reputation - and their answer is more likely to get attention if the question is unanswered (my perspective).

Comment: Fair enough - I guess that's me told ;)

Comment: Obviously that is not the best way to get rep, because apparently, thats not how Jon Skeet gets rep.

Comment: I use the unanswered questions view because I figure those are the questions that needs answers the most.